# Simple C++ not reading EOF

Tags: c++, eof

I'm having a hard time understanding why `while (cin.get(Ch))` doesn't see the `EOF`.  I read in a text file with 3 words, and when I debug my WordCount is at 3 (just what I hoped for).  Then it goes back to the while loop and gets stuck.  `Ch` then has no value.  I thought that after the newline it would read the `EOF` and break out.  I am not allowed to use `<fstream>`, I have to use redirection in DOS.  Thank you so much.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char Ch = ' ';
    int WordCount = 0;
    int LetterCount = 0;

    cout << "(Reading file...)" << endl;

    while (cin.get(Ch))
    {
        if ((Ch == '\n') || (Ch == ' '))
        {
            ++WordCount;
            LetterCount = 0;
        }
        else
            ++LetterCount;
    }

    cout << "Number of words => " << WordCount << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I run it in VS, it gets hung up.  When I redirect a 3 word file ("this if fun!") in the DOS terminal, it says 2 words.

Comment: Are you really supposed to count words, or merely count spaces+newlines.  For example, what about `a.b..c...d` (where `.` is a space)?  That has four words, but six spaces?

Comment: The while loop works fine (i.e., the program reads up to the EOF and exits the loop) on Mac and Linux using clang and gcc. It does not produce the correct output, but that's to be expected because the word counting is erroneous. What compiler are you using, cparnin?

Comment: Thanks for all your help Aaron McDaid.  This is just part of the project.  I have to read in text, then output the frequency of different word lengths- then output the average word length.  Words are counted as only alphabetic characters, numbers, and apostrophes. This is for a 201 class, and once again I feel stuck on something simple.  Stuff like this makes one question the future.  Never give up.  Maybe I need to learn to walk away when I get stuck on "something simple".  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (cin >> Ch)
{   // we get in here if, and only if, the >> was successful
    if ((Ch == '\n') || (Ch == ' '))
    {
        ++WordCount;
        LetterCount = 0;
    }
    else
        ++LetterCount;
}
```

That's the safe, and common, way to rewrite your code safely and with minimal changes.

(Your code is unusual, trying to scan all characters and count whitespace and newlines.  I'll give a more general answer to a slightly different question - how to read in all the words.)

The safest way to check if a stream is finished if `if(stream)`.  Beware of `if(stream.good())` - it doesn't always work as expected and will sometimes quit too early.  The last `>>` into a `char` will not take us to EOF, but the last `>>` into an `int` or `string` *will* take us to EOF.  This inconsistency can be confusing.  Therefore, it is not correct to use `good()`, or any other test that tests EOF.

```
string word;
while(cin >> word) {
   ++word_count;
}
```

There is an important difference between `if(cin)` and `if(cin.good())`.  The former is the [`operator bool` conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).  Usually, in this context, you want to test:

> "did the last extraction operation succeed or fail?"

This is *not* the same as:

> "are we now at EOF?"

After the last word has been read by `cin >> word`, the string is at EOF.  But the `word` is still valid and contains the last word.

TLDR:  The `eof` bit is not important.  The `bad` bit is.  This tells us that the last extraction was a failure.

Answer (score 1):

### The Counting

The program counts newline and space characters as words. In your file contents "this if fun!" I see two spaces and no newline. This is consistent with the observed output indicating two words.

Have you tried looking at your file with a hex editor or something similar to be sure of the exact contents?

You could also change your program to count one more word if the last character read in the loop was a letter. This way you don't have to have newline terminated input files.

### Loop Termination

I have no explanation for your loop termination issues. The while-condition looks fine to me. [`istream::get(char&)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) returns a stream reference. In a while-condition, depending on the C++ level your compiler implements, [`operator bool` or `operator void*`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/basic_ios/operator_bool/) will be applied to the reference to indicate if further reading is possible.

### Idiom

The standard idiom for reading from a stream is

```
char c = 0;
while( cin >> c )
   process(c);
```

I do not deviate from it without serious reason.

Comment: "...goes back in the while loop and gets stuck." Please address.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: addressed

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the correct way to bail out of the loop is:

```
while (cin.good()) {
  char Ch = cin.get();
  if (cin.good()) {
    // do something with Ch
  }
}
```

That said, there are probably better ways to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: There are many ways to properly terminate an input loop. Both yours and and cparnin's look correct to me.

Comment: `good()` is dangerous.  With `char`s it is safe enough, but it will often quit one iteration too early.  For example, if you had `int i;` and `cin >> i`, then there is no safe way to use `good`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid if you notice, in my snippet there's no such thing as `int i; cin >> i;`: in fact, I **deliberately** used `get()` there. Your remark that "`good()` is dangerous" is overly generic as much as it is to say that "C++ is dangerous". Both are dangerous **if used improperly**.

Answer (score 0):

you input file is

this is fun!{EOF}

two spaces make WordCount increase to 2
and then EOF, exit loop! if you add a new line, you input file is

```
this is fun!\n{EOF}
```

Comment: @Chad Parnin I think you should check last character, if it is space or newline, keep wordCount, if it is not, increase wordCount

Answer (score 0):

I took your program loaded it in to visual studio 2013, changed cin to an fstream object that opened a file called stuff.txt which contains the exact characters "This is fun!/n/r" and the program worked. As previous answers have indicated, be careful because if there's not a /n at the end of the text the program will miss the last word. However, I wasn't able to replicate the application hanging in an infinite loop. The code as written looks correct to me.

cin.get(char) returns a reference to an istream object which then has it's operator bool() called which returns false when any of the error bits are set. There are some better ways to write this code to deal with other error conditions... but this code works for me.

Comment: Thanks.  That's something that I needed to know.  I assumed that text in a text file automatically had an EOF at the end.  That's why I get one less word.  As far as Visual Studio: when I run it, it waits for input, then I type something and it just hangs...

Comment: It's important to note that there is no actual EOF character(at least on most OS). EOF is a condition that happens as a result of of reaching the end of an input stream.

If you're using cin, then the program will just keep asking for input infinitely. You type in contents, the program processes them, and then it continues asking for more content. Are you able to type more when the application is hung?

Comment: Yes, like you said it just keeps asking.  I guess I never saw how that hangs, but when I feed it a file it gives me words-1. I think the easy way around this is to set a different condition and cout << WordCount +1.